# Error with G++ while compiling

Tags: g++

I got this error when trying to compile a cpp code

```
c:\mingw\bin>g++ hello.cpp

g++: fatal error: -fuse-linker-plugin, but liblto_plugin-0.dll not found
compilation terminated
```

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have (or the build-system has) specified the flag `-fuse-linker-plugin` which requires the dynamic library file `liblto_plugin-0.dll` to be in your library search path, but the linker cannot find it.

btw, you could have discovered that by carefully reading the error message you got.